# How to show two compatible charts are of the same dimension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I encounter a statement in *Lie Algebras and Lie Groups* by Serre that if two charts $(U,\phi,n)$ and $(U', \phi', n')$ on $X$ are compatible and $V = U\cap U' \ne \emptyset$, then $n=n'$.

A chart $c=(U,\phi,n)$ on $X$ satisfies

1. $U\subseteq X$ is open
2. $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \ge 0$
3. $\phi:U\to \phi(U)\subseteq k^{n}$ is open and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, where $k$ is a field.

Two charts $(U,\phi,n)$ and $(U',\phi',n')$ are said to be compatible if, setting $V = U\cap U'$, the maps $\phi'\circ \phi^{-1}\mid_{\phi(V)}$ and $\phi\circ\phi'^{-1}\mid_{\phi'(V)}$ are analytic.

Most of the materials simply include $n=n'$ implicitly in their definitions, so I have difficulty probing the statement above.

EDIT: The complete definition of analytic for arbitrary $k$ is as follows.

For $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},\cdots, \alpha_{n}), x= (x_{1},\cdots, x_{n})$, denote $x^{\alpha} = (x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}, \cdots, x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}})$. For any open subset $k^{n}$, we say that a function $f = (f_{1},\cdots,f_{m}):U\to k^{m}$ is analytic at $x\in U$ if there exists $r=(r_{1},\cdots,r_{n})\in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ s.t. $f_{j}(y) =\sum\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{n}}c_{\alpha}^{(j)} (y-x)^{\alpha}$ for any $y$ in $B(x,r)=\{y\in k^{n}:|y_{i}-x_{i}|<r_{i} \}$. And the following series converges
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{n}}|c_{\alpha}^{(j)}|r^{\alpha} < \infty
\end{equation}
We say $f$ is analytic if it is analytic everywhere on $U$.

Comment: Is $k$ *any* field; how's analytic defined?

Comment: @guidoar A norm map from $k$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup\{0\}$ is defined, so there is no harm to consider $k=\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Okay, but what's your definition of analytic for arbitrary $k$? For $k = \Bbb R$, the map $\phi' \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism (differentiable with differentiable inverse). But then its jacobian matrix is invertible; in particular, square. Thus $n = n'$. I suppose the complex case could be approached similarly but I haven't done any complex analysis on several variables.

Comment: @guidoar I added the complete definition to the problem description. Could you tell me why the Jacobian matrix is invertible or what theorem should I refer to?

Comment: I was referring only to the real case, in which you can just note that if $f$ is a diffeomorphism then $I = J(f^{-1} \circ f)_p = J(f)_{f^{-1}(p)}J(f)_p$, by the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @guidoar, I figure out a proof.

Let $F=\phi'\circ \phi\mid_{\phi(V)}$, then $F^{-1}=\phi\circ(\phi')^{-1}\mid_{\phi'(V)}$ and both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are analytic. By $id_{\phi(V)}=F^{-1}\circ F$ and the chain rule, we have $I_{n} = J_{F^{-1}\circ F}(p)=J_{F^{-1}}(F(p))\cdot J_{F}(p)$ for all $p\in \phi(V)$. Similarly, by $id_{\phi'(V)}$, we get $I_{n'} = J_{F}(p)\cdot J_{F^{-1}}(F(p))$ for all $p\in \phi(V)$.

According to the property
\begin{equation}
tr(AB)=tr(BA)
\end{equation}
we have $n=tr(I_{n}) = tr(J_{F^{-1}}(F(p))\cdot J_{F}(p)) = tr(J_{F}(p)\cdot J_{F^{-1}}(F(p))) = tr(I_{n'}) =n'$.